# Photoshop operations (color range, blur etc) extremely slow on Azure Win10 VM with GPU support

Tags: virtual-machine, adobe-photoshop, azure

Because of lack of GPU on my computer, I needed to use Photoshop on Azure. Everything is super fast but when I use any kind of effects, and operations like color range Photoshop too slowing, lagging, and waiting. I've changed the Photoshop GPU preference with all possible combination, closed, and opened again but nothing changed.

This problem occurs on virtual machine with no GPU support also. Existing of GPU support changes nothing in short.

I am connecting with VM with RDP.

Whats happening to Photoshop on Azure VM?

Comment: Have you checked it is actually using the remote GPU? RDP connections usually don't if the app was launched via the RDP, only if it was launched prior to connecting. [I have no experience with Azure, but this is standard behaviour for PC>PC RDP]

Comment: Photoshop GPU preference were grayed out when no gpu support, after adding gpu it became functional, and I see "Radeon Instinct MI25 MxGPU" active. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yup, that's the one. I think it's likely you're going to have to ask Adobe about this one. I haven't a clue, sorry.

Comment: Thank! Do file system cause that?

Comment: I don't see how the file system could have any effect one way or another.

Comment: Photoshop uses disk somehow, then I needed to check disk benchmarks and I see Azure is too slow (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHwPT.jpg) This might be the problem.

Comment: . . . Ask Adobe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems Azure never based on SSD performance: CPU, GPU, etc are fine, but there are a few limited and conflicting options for SSD, so it cant be upgradeable as of the year 2023.

So Photoshop is firstly, and heavily based on disk operations; GPU matters secondly...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).